# Android AsyncTask onPostExecute not Getting Triggered

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have the following generally happening for an **AsyncTask**:

```
private class backgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Doing stuff...");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object[] doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // stuff happens here
        ResultsObject results = new ResultsObject(processValue);
        Object[] values = new Object[2];
        values[0] = "STATUS STRING";
        values[1] = results;
        return values;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Object... result) {
        Log.d("actions", "onPostExecute");
        if (this.dialog.isShowing())
            this.dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

However, **onPostExecute** does not appear to be getting triggered. I can validate that everything up until **doInBackground** makes a return call is getting executed. This has to be something obscenely simple that I'm missing here, but I'm stumped. I have other AsyncTasks in this same project, and I have no trouble with them reaching **onPostExecute**.

Comment: `@Override protected void onPostExe.....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overloading `onPostExecute` method and it doesn't get used. Use this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    super.onPostExecute(o);
    Log.d("actions", "onPostExecute");
    if (this.dialog.isShowing())
        this.dialog.dismiss();
}
```

**Note** the `@Override` annotation, it comes very useful in times like this. It will show an error if the method you are trying to override doesn't exist.

Comment: I didn't have that in there in other instances, but it seems to have done the trick here. Or maybe it was making an array declaration when extending AsyncTask to now read `AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object[]>`. I dunno. Either way, thanks!